# Google Map View can not display on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, browser

Hi I am trying to show map in the android emulator. but it cant display google map in the map view. and also not connect www.google.com from browser on android emulator.
so is there any settings regarding to run internet on emulator.
can anyone help me out from this problem.

Comment: Did you check firewall settings? Usually works with no extra settings.

Comment: at present i am working on MAC OS then where is exactly firewall settings if can help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this within the manifest tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`