# android google map view problem

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to display google map in android emulator. i also follow the step described in below link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

when i run my application it will not display google map. just display grids like below.
[image]

Please help me to show google map.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked several times on SO. Please try the search function, you will get the solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+maps+not+showing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113657/google-map-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this link:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

and keep in mind  ur project should be signed in to get the google map data..otherwise u will find only the grids..

Comment: but it doesn't work it will also show the same gridview instead of gooogle map

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, once you get the MD5 fingerprint, go to this url http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and paste the MD5 fingerprint. Once you've done that, copy the API key onto the XML layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

run  -->  debug Configurations... -->select ur application --> target tab ---> add below line in Additional Emulator Command Line Options

e.g 
             -http-proxy http://myproxy:port/

where myproxy= write ur proxy server name (my proxy server is 192.168.0.1)
      port   = port number (my port number )
it like,
   -http-proxy http://192.168.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Try it by  changing debug.keystore file name and create MD5 again and generate key.